# java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation( where the column has both int values and few values are N/A)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a table as below:

column1 -  12312,12235,43242,53465,82745
  column2 -  12,45,56,N/A,N/A

and my java program is as below:

```
public Map<Integer, String> fetchResultValue(String query)
        throws SQLException, IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException,
        ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {
    Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection(true);
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            m.put(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
        }
        return m;
    } finally {
        this.cleanResources(con, pstmt);
    }
}
```

and Im getting that exception for reading column2 values and I initially tried using rs.getInte(2) instead of rs.getString(2) but even then i was getting that exception so how do I read that column values.

Comment: what is the value of 'query'?

Comment: My query is like select column1,column2 from table where column3='xyz'; and the datatype for column2 is varchar2